# Column "file" is of type oid but expression is of type byte

Tags: java, sql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to implement file upload with JSF 2.3:

```
@Inject
@Push
private PushContext uploadProgress;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NewProcedure.class.getName());
private Part file;

public Part getFile()
{
    return file;
}

public void setFile(Part file)
{
    this.file = file;
}

public void upload() throws SQLException
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
            //FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path)
            )
        {

            long lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int pushInterval = 1000;
            long totalRead = 0;
            long size = file.getSize();

            int bytesRead = 0;
            final byte[] chunck = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(chunck)) != -1)
            {
//                    outputStream.write(chunck, 0, bytesRead);
                totalRead += bytesRead;

                if (System.currentTimeMillis() > lastTimestamp + pushInterval)
                {
                    lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    uploadProgress.send(100.0 * totalRead / size); // Make sure this isn't sent more often than once per second.
                }
            }

            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            // insert into database file
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            boolean committed = false;
            try
            {
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);

                ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PROCEDURE_FILES (ID, PROCEDURE_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE) "
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                ps.setInt(1, obj.number);
                ps.setInt(2, obj.number);
                ps.setString(3, "tests");
                ps.setBinaryStream(4, inputStream);

                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.close();

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally
            {
                if (!committed)
                {
                    conn.rollback();
                }

                if (ps != null)
                {
                    ps.close();
                }
                conn.close();
            }

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Upload successfully ended!"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Upload failed!"));
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to insert the file directly into database but I get error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "file" is of type oid but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

What is the proper way to insert the file into the Database?
Probably I need to use other Java Object to store the file?

P.S I tried this:

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException
    {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0xFFFF];

            for (int len; (len = is.read(buffer)) != -1;)
                os.write(buffer, 0, len);

            os.flush();

            return os.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    public void upload() throws SQLException
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();

                byte[] bytesFromInputStream = getBytesFromInputStream(inputStream);
                ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesFromInputStream);


                long lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int pushInterval = 1000;
                long totalRead = 0;
                long size = file.getSize();

                int bytesRead = 0;
                final byte[] chunck = new byte[1024];
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(chunck)) != -1)
                {
//                    outputStream.write(chunck, 0, bytesRead);
                    totalRead += bytesRead;

                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > lastTimestamp + pushInterval)
                    {
                        lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        uploadProgress.send(100.0 * totalRead / size); // Make sure this isn't sent more often than once per second.
                    }
                }

                Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
                // insert into database file
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                boolean committed = false;
                try
                {
                    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

                    ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PROCEDURE_FILES (ID, PROCEDURE_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE) "
                        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    ps.setInt(1, obj.number);
                    ps.setInt(2, obj.number);
                    ps.setString(3, file.getSubmittedFileName());
                    ps.setBinaryStream(4, input, input.available());

                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.close();

                    conn.commit();
                    committed = true;
                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {}
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ps.setBinaryStream(4, inputStream, file.length());` 
Quote: `The length parameter to setBinaryStream must be correct. There is no way to indicate that the stream is of unknown length. If you are in this situation, you must read the stream yourself into temporary storage and determine the length. Now with the correct length you may send the data from temporary storage on to the driver. `  Problem is `file` is actually a `Part` (JavaMail?) in which case you'll have to query the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: @Stavr00 How I can set the length? From which part of the code I can get the length size?

Comment: You have to get it from `getSize()` or read in the whole stream into a `ByteArayInputStream` if it returns -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the while-loop reading inputStream.

The reading occurs by setting the binary input stream of the column `file`.

This needs another kind of progress indication.

What now happened is that the inputStream was read to the end, and the prepared statement could only read 0 bytes.

---

```
public void upload() throws SQLException {
    if (file != null) {
        try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {

            long lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int pushInterval = 1000;
            long totalRead = 0;
            long size = file.getSize();

            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            // insert into database file
            boolean committed = false;
            try {
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);

                try (PreparedStatement ps =
                        conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PROCEDURE_FILES"
                                + " (ID, PROCEDURE_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE) "
                                + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                    ps.setInt(1, obj.number);
                    ps.setInt(2, obj.number);
                    ps.setString(3, "tests");
                    ps.setBinaryStream(4, inputStream);

                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (!committed) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
                conn.close();
            }

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage("Upload successfully ended!"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage("Upload failed!"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I need the while-loop to send back to client updates about the upload progress. Can you show me code sample please?

Comment: You would have to wrap your upload progress code by extending an `InputStream` class and letting the `executeUpdate` consume that stream.

Comment: I tried to implement whole stream into a ByteArayInputStream but I get the same error. Post is updated. Any ideas? I get the same error.

Comment: @PeterPenzov I wrote the code as I think it should work. Assuming that setFile was called prior to upload and such small details.

Comment: (An InputStream can be read - in general - only once: till the end. So one has to be careful with the control flow, not reusing file, inputStream or such.)

Comment: Thanks, I will test it later today.